# How fix AddressOf requires a relaxed conversation to the delegate error

Tags: c#, vb.net, delegates, address-operator

Sorry, this is a mix of C# and VB.Net

I have a C# class with with 2 delegates:

```
public delegate string GetSettingDelegate(string key);
public event GetSettingDelegate GetSettingEvent;

public delegate void SetSettingDelegate(string key, string value);
public event SetSettingDelegate SetSettingEvent;
```

In a VB class I add handlers to the event:

```
AddHandler _gisCtrl.SetSettingEvent, AddressOf SetSetting
AddHandler _gisCtrl.GetSettingEvent, AddressOf GetSetting
```

When I try and remove the handlers:

```
RemoveHandler _gisCtrl.SetSettingEvent, AddressOf SetSetting
RemoveHandler _gisCtrl.GetSettingEvent, AddressOf GetSetting
```

SetSetting is OK but GetSetting throws a warning:

The AddressOf expression has no effect in this context because the method arguments to AddressOf requires a relaxed conversation to the delagate type of the event.

Here are the methods

```
Private Sub SetSetting(ByVal key As String, ByVal value As String)
    KernMobileBusinessLayer.[Global].Settings.SetValue(key, value)
End Sub

Private Function GetSetting(ByVal key As String)
    Return KernMobileBusinessLayer.[Global].Settings.GetString(key)
End Function
```

Any idea how to fix this and why it is thrown in the first place? The 2 delegates/events/methods look similar enough that I don't know why one is OK and one throws a warning.

Comment: GetSetting(), as defined above, would return Object, not String. I think max has it right.

Comment: Use Option Strict On to let the compiler catch these kind of mistakes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

probably your `GetSetting` function must fully match `GetSettingDelegate` signature:

```
Private Function GetSetting(ByVal key As String) as String
```

Comment: Thanks. Obvious now! I marked yours as the answer as you answered first.

Answer (score 7):

your vb code:

```
Private Function GetSetting(ByVal key As String)
```

doesn't match the C# delegate definition:

```
public delegate string GetSettingDelegate(string key);
```

you should specify a return type in your VB implementation, like this:

```
Private Function GetSetting(ByVal key As String) As String
```